# Make a PHP variable be recognized

Tags: php

I've been working on a php dynamic drop down list that scans a folder on the web server and list its contents it works hears relevant selection of the code.

```
<?php


foreach(glob(dirname(rootdir) . '/path/username/*') as $filename){
$filename = basename($filename);
echo "<option value='filepath/username/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
```

However if i use a variable to populate part of the file path the variable doesn't get added to the path.

```
<?php
$name = "jsmith";

foreach(glob(dirname(rootdir) . '/path/$name/*') as $filename){
$filename = basename($filename);
echo "<option value='filepath/$name/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
```

$name = "jsmith"

The result I'm looking for is /path/$name/* = /path/jsmith/ 
and
filepath/$name/ = filepath/jsmith/

How do I get the glob(dirname) and option value=' recognize the variables?

Comment: Variables are not interpolated within single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either concatenate the variable with the string or wrap the string in double quotes so the variable is parsed.

**Double Quotes**

```
<?php
$name = "jsmith";

foreach(glob(dirname(rootdir) . "/path/$name/*") as $filename){
$filename = basename($filename);
echo "<option value='filepath/$name/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
```

**Concatenate**

```
<?php
$name = "jsmith";

foreach(glob(dirname(rootdir) . '/path/' . $name . '/*') as $filename){
$filename = basename($filename);
echo "<option value='filepath/$name/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes [do not interpolate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).  (i.e. Variables in the string will not be replaced with their values.)  However, double-quotes do interpolate.

You'll need to change `'/path/$name/*'` to `"/path/$name/*"` or use string concatenation with `'/path/' . $name . '/*'` instead.

Also, you should be careful with accepting user-controlled input for `$name` as it may lead to a [directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).